# How will i make the first div visible by default/on pageload?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have dynamic content and want the latest content/div visible. How will I edit the code in the ts file below to achieve this?

```
ngOnInit() {
    var navBar = document.getElementById('navbar');
    navBar.addEventListener('click', (e: any)=> {
      var divDisplay = document.getElementById(e.target.hash.substring(1));
      var allDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.container div');
      allDivs.forEach((div: any) => div.style.display = 'none');
      divDisplay.style.display = 'block';
    })
  }
```

Html:

```
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#section1">Link 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section2">Link 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section3">Link 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section4">Link 4</a></li>  
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="section1">Section 1</div>
  <div id="section2">Section 2</div>
  <div id="section3">Section 3</div>
  <div id="section4">Section 4</div>
</div>
```

Pls check the [demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3pnuj8)

Comment: What do you mean by _latest_?

Comment: @Ced, I think the demo link is missing

Comment: I am using ngFor , so if I add `<div id="section5">Section 5</div>` ,  this should be the latest content/div visible , here s the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3pnuj8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A solution using CSS only

You can achieve the goal using CSS selector: `:not(:last-child)`

#### Example (based on your html):

```css
.container > div:not(:last-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#section1">Link 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section2">Link 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section3">Link 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section4">Link 4</a></li>  
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="section1">Section 1</div>
  <div id="section2">Section 2</div>
  <div id="section3">Section 3</div>
  <div id="section4">Section 4</div>
</div>
```

#### Useful links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child
- https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:not